# Background a foreground running download tool like wget only after auth

Tags: process, wget, curl

A tricky one - if you use wget with auth, it works like this:

1. you run wget in foreground
2. No other process can start until you enter password
3. wget asks you for password
4. you input password
5. you wait for download

Is it possible to make wget (or similar tool) background after #4? Note - if you run wget in background (#1), of course it foregrounds for #3, but #2 is then violated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the login information on the command line:

`wget --http-user="username" --http-password="password" http://some.url &`

Then you can background it immediately.